# How to display objects inside an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of objects and I want to display them in order.  I want to assign each attribute or property of the object to DOM objects such as "title" to h1 or "description" to p etc. and have each object inside a new div element. I'm sort of new to javascript so I'm really not sure where to start here.

```
var ads = [
{
    title: "Photo Play Paper Collections",
    description: "Don't miss these brand new Photo Play Paper Collections!",

},
{
    title: "Foil & Foiling Accessories",
    description: "Once you add this color & shine to your paper, wood, fabric, or other porous surfaces you'll want to do it over and over again.",

},
];
```

When I try to display this

```
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=ads
```

It just returns as

[object Object],[object Object]

First of all, how to I get it to display the actual information stored, and secondly how would I append each attribute to an element using javascript?  Sorry this is sort of vague.  The only things I've seen involve using angular or react.  Is there a somewhat simple way to do this using only pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, how to I get it to display the actual information stored?

You could use JSON.stringify to turn it into the json string representation:

```
  document.getElementById("test").textContent = JSON.stringify(ads);
```

> and secondly how would I append each attribute to an element using javascript?

That is slightly more complicated. You would have to manually iterate the array and build up your own DOM nodes:

```
 const parent = document.getElementById("test");

 for(const { title, description } of ads) {
  // Build up new dom nodes
  const headline = document.createElement("h1");
  headline.textContent = title;
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.textContent = description;
  // append them:
  parent.appendChild(headline);
  parent appendChild(container);
 }
```

Comment: I'd avoid putting `JSON.stringify` directly in `innerHTML` without escaping. That is what `textContent` is for.

Comment: @ray agreed. ..

Comment: Thank you this does help!  And for the for loop, I wouldn't need to stringify the attributes or create text nodes?  Or is that what textContent does?  Sorry for my ignorance lol

Comment: @bexter yup, setting `textContent` creates a new text node and appends that to the elements childs.

Comment: Also, why do you use const instead of var?  Is it acceptable to use a variable instead?

Comment: @bexter yes you could also use `let` or `var`, but I prefer to use const whenever possible as it makes the code predictable